# Apache Reverse Proxy Redirection

Tags: apache, proxy

I've a question about which is the best way to redirect an url using apache as a reverse proxy.
At this moment I've 2 reverse proxys configured to access to differents aplicactions that run over the same database. Now we want to eliminate the oldest of those apps, but we still needing that the url used to access to that aplication redirect to the other aplication.
Is the best way to do this use something like this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName website.com/oldapp
  RedirectPermanent / website.com/newapp
</VirtualHost>
```